# SSRS Sporadic email sending issue

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, smtpclient, windows-server-2016

In the past couple of weeks, I've started to get (on a more and more regular basis) errors with sending emails via scheduled subscriptions in SSRS 2016 (on Windows Server 2016). The error I'm seeing is:

ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

This doesn't happen every time. For example I've got a report that should have been sent at 1pm - it failed with the above error but as SSRS retries every 15 minutes it actually got sent 30 minutes later.

From what I could find by googling, this might in some way relate to TLS 1.2 - but I can't see anywhere in SSRS where you define what it should use. I upgraded the .NET Framework to 4.8 but that has made no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be with TLS and the server configuration.

To fix it, I disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 - I also added the following keys to the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```